# Перезагрузка страницы в WebView с помощью Swipe Refresh - не перезагружает

Tags: webview

Я создаю с помощью WebView небольшую программу для мобильной версии сайта под android через android studio

есть код MainAktivity

```
package com.example.porno;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private WebView WebView;
private SwipeRefreshLayout SwipeRefresh;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);

    WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // включаем поддержку JavaScript
    WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // указываем страницу загрузки
    WebView.loadUrl("http://m.mysite.ru");
    WebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    //Настраиваем выполнение OnRefreshListener для данной activity:
    SwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Останавливаем обновление:
            SwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false)
            ;
        }
    }, 5000);
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && WebView.canGoBack()) {
        WebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Так же код layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Все работает, сайт загружается, когда переходишь по ссылкам сайта, и тянешь вниз, появляется колесико перезагрузки, но сама страница не перезагружается.... Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем я ошибся...

Answer (score 1):

В метод onCreate добавьте

```
 public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
       LASTURL = url;
   }
```

Зарегистрируйте константу

```
private LASTURL;
```

Измените на вот это

```
public void run() {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        wv.loadUrl(LASTURL);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Как то так

Comment: пипец я идиот был)